# Connecting to Bluetooth Personal Area Network Fails

Tags: windows-7, connection, bluetooth, network-adapter, pan

I'm trying to connect to my phone's Bluetooth PAN but nothing happens when I do.

I click the button that says "Connect Using" which gives me two options:
[Option 1] "Direct Connection" 

                           [Option 2] "Access Point".

[image]

Both options result in a dialog that says "Connection Successful" but my Bluetooth Network Connection adapter still shows it as "Not connected".

[image]

I have the latest drivers from the Bluetooth website and they are functioning well as you can see in this screenshot.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: 
Go to Services > Bluetooth Support Service > change "Log on as": to "This account".

For USERNAME, write "Local Service" (without the quotes). The password that you can't read shows some encrypted password that you can't (and don't need to) change.

Restart the processes, and the rest will now work! The Bluetooth icon with the Red Cross will disappear.